# App_Code folder in ASP.NET project in VIsual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, app-code

at vs2008 i could set App_Code folder, but at vs2010 i can not do it, that's why i put my dataset's and class' to App_Data folder. Either I do not know even App_Data folder is secure? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remember, that `Web Site Project` can contain `App_Code` folder and `Web Application Project` can't! Because all project is for code.

Comment: is the reason why code-intelligence does not work on class' created in App_Code ? Either how can i hide my dataset 's ? I wouldn't that my dataset degisgner could be read

Comment: @softwaremonster: Very glad that it helped! :) It would be very nice if you could also upvote my answer.

Comment: i may only mark your answer as correct answer, i have'not enough reputation to vote up :( thanks again !

Comment: @softwaremonster: now you're able  I guess :) nice to help you!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add the App_Code folder, you have to manually add the folder.
Add->Add New folder--> you have to give it the folder name "App_Code"
when you do it, and vs2010 automatically will change its folder type.

good luck

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use standalone class files (in "App_Code" dir) in VS 2010 project, be sure set the File Properties > Build Action for each *.cs or *.vb file to "Compile" in the Properties > Advanced dialog.

Also, use the same namespace as your project and these standalone classes will be readily  available to the rest of your project.

Took me a bit to realize the default setting in my VS was "Content" instead of "Compile."

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried right-clicking on the project in the Solution Explorer, selected 'Add...' and looked under ASP.NET folders?

From memory, even previous versions of VS don't automatically put the App_Code folder in your project by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you just create a folder called App_Code it will recognise it as the App_Code you want, it is strange that in the add .net folder it doesnt appear.

This the route I took for it, and it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Workaround:
>
> If we are using App_Code in a web application project, we need to
>   rename into any other folder name.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chiranth/archive/2014/02/19/visual-studio-2012-unexpected-behavior-crash-and-irrelevant-errors.aspx

Answer (score -2):

I hope this will help you - the .cs files should not be placed in a folder.  Just put them in the project, alone, and not in a folder.  Then your classes will be visible.  This is a difference in VS 2010.